# How to send notification for specific user in socketio?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and have run into something that seems pretty weird, I'm having trouble sending notifications to a specific user, I cannot send any signal to the specific user I want to connect with via MVC Model and socket.io.
Here is my code:

```
let onlineUsers = [];

const getUser = (idUser) => {
  return onlineUsers.find((user) => user.idUser === idUser);
};

socket.on("send_notify", ({ receiverID }) => {
      const receiver = getUser(receiverID);
      console.log(receiver.socketId)
      _io.to(receiver.socketId).emit("receive_notify", receiverID);
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to all of this :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the efficient way but I have used this method in one of my project.

Your server will emit event using receiver id:

```
socket.on("send_notify", ({ receiverID }) => {
      const receiver = getUser(receiverID);
      console.log(receiver.socketId)
      _io.emit(`${receiverID}_receive_notify`, receiverID);
});
```

Now your front end socket connection will listen like this:

```
socket.on(`${receiverID}_receive_notify`, () => {
     //some code
});
```

NOTE: if receiver id is something not to be disposed to front end then you can use either user id or user email or may be user phone number whatever field is unique for each user.